# Customising splash image of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

Where can I find the splash image which is shown while starting QGIS, and how to customise it?

I am developing a GIS software for myself based on QGIS, but I don't want to just start anew with QGIS's include and lib as it cost much time and energy. Instead, with the QGIS interface, I can pay more attention to create my own algorithms and add them to QGIS as plugins like sextante. Yet,I got my favoured bgimage before and still want to use it in this software I am developing.

Answer (score 20):

Note that since QGIS 3.0, you can override the splashscreen by manually editing the QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini file in the current user profile.

### 1. Enable Customization

Go to *Settings/Interface Customization...* then tick the "*Enable customization*" checkbox
If you skip this step, the QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini will not exist

### 2. Access QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini

To access the file, go to *Settings/User profiles/Open Active Profile Folder*.
The file is located at ./QGIS/QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini

### 3. Edit .ini

Add a key named "splashpath" in the ini file, which points to a folder which contains an image called "splash.png" (mandatory name and extension)

Example:

```
[Customization]
splashpath=/home/myimagefolder/
Docks=true
Docks\AdvancedDigitizingTools=true
Docks\BookmarksDockWidget=true
Docks\Browser=true
Docks\Browser2=true
Docks\DockWidget=true
Docks\GPSInformation=true
Docks\LayerOrder=true
Docks\Layers=true
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini file you only need the path to where the image 'splash.png' is located.
If you drop the filename 'splash.png' it should work

Example:

```
[Customization]
splashpath=C:/qgis-splash/
```

The default image size is 600x300
Tested on QGIS 3.4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows as operating system (based on provided splash.png directory path) you have to escape the backslash in the path. This path should lead to the **directory** where the splash.png file is placed. Splash screen PNG file have to be called **splash.png** in order to QGIS use it correctly. In your case the path should look like this:

splashpath = C:\\Temp\\QGIS-3.4.8-1-64bit\\

In case you want to use splashscreen from outer directory (eg. shared directory - samba):

splashpath = \\\\UR.IP.Add.ress:\\Temp\\QGIS-3.4.8-1-64bit\\