# Customise splash image

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-customization

I would like to change the splash screen of QGIS 3.4 LTR. I read the instructions from [Customise the splash image of QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68988/customise-the-splash-image-of-QGIS) but I didn't manage to change it.

Does the overwrite of the splash screen also work with QGIS 3.4? I tried to add:

```
[Customization] splashpath=C:\Temp\QGIS-3.4.8-1-64bit\splash.png
```

to `QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini`, but the splash screen is replaced by with square.

I guess it must be an issue related to the path, must it be relative? Or is the size of the picture important?