# QGIS 3.14 splash screen

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am trying to  change Qgis splash screen. I edit QGISCUSTOMIZATION3.ini and put this in

```
[Customization]
splashpath=C:\\GIS\\
...
```

In folder C:\GIS\ i put png image splash.png, but when I start qgis splash screen not change from default.

Comment: Answered elsewhere, I suspect you've not enabled customization in the settings... interface customization.... dialog.

Comment: It is possible to find the solution at this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68988/customising-splash-image-of-qgis